# Angular Ui-Router Only Match "/" Not Children

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two main routes in my Angular app. "/" and "/something/{id}". I'd expect any other route (e.g. "site.com/#/tree") to throw an error, however it's being routed to my main route.

```
        $stateProvider
            .state('main', {
                parent: 'app',
                url: '/',
                data: {
                    authorities: [],
                    pageTitle: 'Main'
                },
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
                        controller: MainController
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('main.id', {
                url: '^/main/{id:int}',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
                        controller: MainController
                    }
                }
            });
```

Is there a way to make my main state only match the *exact* "/" url?

Comment: unfortunately the state provider doesn't work like that.  anything after the hash is a parameter, not handled by the browser as a route segment.  You can use an `.otherwise` clause to route non matches to a different view, but that doesn't really work right with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
app.config(["$urlRouterProvider","$stateProvider",
    function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
        //reroute to error page
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise({templateUrl:'/404.html'});

        //the rest of your $stateProvider code goes here.
    }
]);
```